# How do I disable warnings at initialization in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Ever since I installed emacs24 some tiny insignificant piece of my configuration files stopped working. Since I don't really care about this error and It does not affect me I just want Emacs to shut up about initialization warnings and just open the scratch buffer (as it is it opens a second buffer with some error stuff).

Is there a way to do this without having to sit hours to debug lisp code I don't understand?

I really can't post the configuration file because it's really really big and messy, but this is the warning I get:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/sofia/.emacs':
>
> Symbol's function definition is void: plist-to-alist
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

In a nutshell, I don't want to ensure normal operation, I just want one buffer when opening emacs

Comment: This won't directly answer your question, but I think [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14183331/753160) explains how to fix the error instead of ignoring it.

Comment: +1 to fixing or removing the error instead of ignoring or masking it. A good programmer should take pride in their tools. The highest level of the backtrace should point you right to the offending line in your `.emacs` - then if you don't want to invest in a fix you can remove the containing sexp.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed this particular problem, but in general, yes, that's not the answer. I want to get rid of those warnings, It happens often and I really don't want to sit and fix elisp code every time it happens.

Comment: You can never *guarantee* that your existing config will be 100% compatible with a new release of Emacs, so if you're not in a position to resolve problems with your config, then upgrading Emacs becomes risky. I would strongly recommend that you revert back to the version of Emacs in which your config worked, rather than running with a broken configuration. Postpone the upgrade until you have the time to fix the problems.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the obvious -- i.e., search your source files for the term `plist-to-alist` and you will see exactly where the problem is -- a library containing that function definition has not been loaded, or the function no longer exists.  The link above by Carl Groner also offers a solution to create the missing function yourself.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*I'm not saying that it's a good idea to do this* (in fact I very much agree with @Carl Groner and @rashimoto that masking errors instead of fixing them is usually a Bad Idea™), but at your own risk try adding the following to the top of your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(setq warning-minimum-level :emergency)
```

This tells Emacs not to warn you about anything except problems

> that will seriously impair Emacs operation soon if you do not attend to [them] promptly.

By contrast, the default value of `warning-minimum-level` is `:warning`, which causes Emacs to warn you about

> data or circumstances that are not inherently wrong, but raise suspicion of a possible problem.

More info about warnings and options for dealing with them [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Basics.html) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Options.html).